# How to display nested array objects in ngx datatable?

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I'm trying to get the object data from nested array in ngx datatable column, Could someone help me  how to do it? Please find my example

[https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-datatable-kglni5?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts[enter](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-datatable-kglni5?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts%5Benter) link description here][1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-datatable-kglni5?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `cellTemplate` for your column with `<ng-template>` to customize the displayed value in the column.

### Solution 1

> .component.html

```
<ng-template #batterTemplate let-row="row" let-value="value" let-i="index">
    <ng-template ngFor let-obj [ngForOf]="value">
        <strong> ID: {{ obj.id }} </strong>
        <span>Type: {{ obj.type }}</span>
        <br />
    </ng-template>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #toppingTemplate let-row="row" let-value="value" let-i="index">
    <ng-template ngFor let-obj [ngForOf]="value">
        <strong> ID: {{ obj.id }} </strong>
        <span>Type: {{ obj.type }}</span>
        <br />
    </ng-template>
</ng-template>
```

And make sure you need to **define column(s) with `cellTemplate` in `OnInit` or `AfterViewInit` method** so the `ngx-datatable` will take effect.

> .component.ts

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('batterTemplate') batterTemplate!: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('toppingTemplate') toppingTemplate!: TemplateRef<any>;

  ...

  columns = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.columns = [
      { name: 'Name', prop: 'name' },
      { name: 'Batters', prop: 'batters.batter', cellTemplate: this.batterTemplate },
      { name: 'Toppings', prop: 'topping', cellTemplate: this.toppingTemplate }
    ];
  }
}
```

[Sample Solution 1 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-datatable-ji6yul)

---

### Solution 2:

Yes, you can **wrap the `<ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template>` in the `<ngx-datatable-column>`**.

> .component.html

```
<ngx-datatable 
  [rows]="rows" 
  class="material" 
  [loadingIndicator]="loadingIndicator"
  [columnMode]="'force'" 
  [headerHeight]="50" 
  [footerHeight]="50" 
  [rowHeight]="'auto'"
  [columns]="columns" 
  [reorderable]="reorderable">

    <ngx-datatable-column name="Name" prop="name"></ngx-datatable-column>

    <ngx-datatable-column name="Batter" prop="batters.batter">
        <ng-template let-row="row" let-value="value" let-i="index" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
            <ng-template ngFor let-obj [ngForOf]="value">
                <strong> ID: {{ obj.id }} </strong>
                <span>Type: {{ obj.type }}</span>
                <br />
            </ng-template>
        </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>

    <ngx-datatable-column name="Toppings" prop="topping">
        <ng-template let-row="row" let-value="value" let-i="index" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
            <ng-template ngFor let-obj [ngForOf]="value">
                <strong> ID: {{ obj.id }} </strong>
                <span>Type: {{ obj.type }}</span>
                <br />
            </ng-template>
        </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>

</ngx-datatable>
```

[Sample Solution 2 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-datatable-w9sm9j)

Comment: Can we do this by using <ngx-datatable-column> in ngx datatable? I'm I don't want to use the columns in .ts file.Can we do it?

Comment: Hi @Jhansiravula, yes you can, I had updated my answer for your requirement.

Comment: Thank a lot :) @Yong Shun